# How to access protected method of Java jar file's class

Tags: jruby, jrubyonrails

I am using a Java command-line application (which is open-source) as a jar file for my `jrubyonrails` project. The main application is like following

```
public class Decoder extends Annotator {
  public Decoder() {
    super();
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    ... // Do something that I don't want
    myDesiredMethod();
    ... // And some other thing
  }
...
}
```

There are many steps which I want to skip, I only want `myDesiredMethod` function. And it is a `protected` method from the parent `Annotator` class.

```
public class Annotator extends Helper {
...
  protected SomeClass myDesiredMethod(boolean reMap) throws Exception { ... }
...
}
```

`Annotator` class does not have any public constructor so that I cannot:

```
ann = Annotator.new
```

It raises this error: `TypeError: no public constructors for Annotator`.

Then I try to implement another class which inherits `Annotator` in order to access `myDesiredMethod`. This is the `jruby` code I have tried so far

```
require 'java'
require 'decoder.jar'

java_import java.util.ArrayList
java_import java.lang.StringBuilder

module MyModule
  class RuDecoder < Annotator
    include_package 'com.decoder'
    def self.my_method
        myDesiredMethod
    end
end
```

It returns the error: `NoMethodError: undefined method 'myDesiredMethod' for MyModule::RuDecoder:Class`. Seems `jruby` does not look for the method of the parent class.

Is there any solution in my case, I don't want to rebuild the java library to jar and manually put it into my program every time it has an update.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out that I made thing over-complicated. I can call the default constructor of `Annotator` as following:

```
  constructors = Annotator.java_class.declared_constructors.first
  constructors.accessible = true
  annotator = constructors.new_instance.to_java
```

And use simple call `myDesiredMethod`: `annotator.myDesiredMethod`